# Proofs that show a number isn't a member of the set by showing the number is smaller than the minimum of the set?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question

I was reading a paper on optimization and came across the following proof technique:

> We'll show the minimum of the set $A$ is $b$. Then we'll show that $c \lt b$. Then we'll conclude c is not a member of $A$.

I was wondering if there was any (famous) proofs that used this technique.

Comment: What makes that technique so special? It is totally obvious.

Comment: I have no doubts about how its obvious. I hadn't previously seen a result proved explicitly with this line of reasoning, and therefore asked if there were more. (Which I don't doubt that there are.)